# Minimum and Maximum Probability you walk free?

Tags: probability

**The problem**

You are about to go on trial for a crime you did not commit! There are $3$ Judges, $J_1 , J_2 $ and $J_3$. You are told beforehand that the probability $J_1$ and $J_2$ make the right decision (decide you are innocent ) is $p$. The probability that $J_3$ thinks you are innocent is $\frac{1}{2}$.

You will walk free if at least $2$ Judges think you are innocent.

**First case**

If all judges make their decisions independently then the probability you walk free is quite a simple calculation:

$p^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} +p^2 \cdot\frac{1}{2} + p (1-p) \frac{1}{2} + (1-p)p\frac{1}{2} = p$.

**Complicated cases**

It is possible however to see answers greater than and less than $p$ is we assume judges are not independent!

Consider $p =\frac{1}{4} $. Let's say the judges make their decision by sampling one Unifrom $[0,1]$ RV called $U$.

1. If $U < \frac{1}{4}$ then $J_1$ says innocent and the others guilty.
2. If $\frac{1}{4} < U <\frac{1}{2}$ then $J_2$ says innocent and the others guilty.
3. If $ \frac{1}{2} <U$ then $J_3$ says innocent and the others guilty.

Notice for each Judge we have the correct probabilities of saying you are innocent. And so always one and exactly one Judge will think you are innocent, hence your probability of walking free is $0$. Far less than the independent case $\frac{1}{4}$

Similarly lets say $p = \frac{3}{4}$ and the judges again all use $U$ to decide your fate by the following:

1. If $U < \frac{3}{4}$ then $J_1$ says innocent.
2. If $\frac{1}{4} < U $ then $J_2$ says innocent.
3. If $ U < \frac{1}{4}$ or $ U  > \frac{3}{4} $ $J_3$ says innocent.

Notice again all our probabilities are consistent with constraints, yet however, with probability $1$ you will walk free! Nice.

**My question**

For a general $p$ what is the maximum and minimum probability you could possibly walk free under.

**Edit**

I found the correct answer.

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own question if you wish.